# How to clear RAID "Error Occurred(0)" member disk message?

Tags: raid, software-raid, intel-rst

I had a bad SATA cable which caused an "Error Occurred(0)" message to appear on one of the member disks. I replaced the cable and everything works fine now, but the message remains and the RAID logon prompt stays on longer than normal unless I press escape. How do I get rid of this message? I don't see anything in RAID BIOS that would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cleared this error using Intel Rapid Storage Technology software.