# Intel RAID0 physical device error occurred(0), Win7 won't run but disks seem OK - is it salvageable?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, raid, chkdsk

I booted my MSI Win7 laptop and noticed the Intel RAID boot info says `Error occurred(0)`, pretty much like the screen shot here: [How to clear RAID "Error Occurred(0)" member disk message?](https://superuser.com/questions/1123974/how-to-clear-raid-error-occured0-member-disk-message)

Windows starts loading, shows the Windows logo but then hangs with a blank screen showing only the mouse pointer.

I then discovered (and cursed myself for not realising how stupid this was when I got the machine) that it has 2 500GB Hitachi HDDs, and they are combined into one RAID0 volume.

Then the volume is partitioned (when I bought it already) into 4 volumes, with the OS on C: and the data on D:, plus a 10GB volume labeled BIOS_RVY and a 100MB volume labeled 'System'.

I ran the startup repair utility, and that didn't detect any issues.

I booted up with my rescue disk and ran chkdsk on C: and D:, and it didn't find any problems.

I checked some of the files on the filesystem, and they look fine.

I have a backup from 3 days ago, so I could replace the hard drives and restore, but I'd like to avoid that.

My question is whether I can fix the hard drive that's in error without needing to reinstall everything and restore my backup (they're not disk clones or images, they're standard backed-up files).

Answer (score 0):

Checkdisk startup is irrelevant. If the system boots fine, you can check each drive with **HD Tune**. Get that, perform a scan and see if you detect anything bad. A single bad sector can cause warnings/errors in the RAID0 configuration, but it does not really mean that you will have data loss. Also, you should check the SMART status of the drives in the array using the same HDTune program.

Comment: hdtunepro_560_trial.exe won't run from the recovery prompt - I guess it only runs in Windows: "subsystem needed to support the image type is not present" is all it says before exiting. Did you think I could run Windows? Or am I meant to unpack the hdtune app from its download file or something?

Comment: If you get to the mouse pointer you should be fine. Try a quick safe mode start (HDTune should work from safe mode too), then a restart, then to alt-ctrl-del for a task manager to run explorer or try to spawn a cmd before the GUI. Also, only disabling the video driver may also get windows running.

Comment: I wish it was fine but no such luck. It doesn't get as far as the login screen even - I can't get into safe mode, and I can't get the task manager with `ctrl-alt-del`. I'm going to try getting it going from a bootable CD. So even if I get as far as running HDTune, will I be able to fix the errors, or does it just detect them?

Comment: It is very good for detecting them. Any bad sectors will clearly show at a full scan and also the SMART status may tell you good valuable info. To fix bad sectors if found, you'll want to try something like HDD Regenerator.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The final result is that I have managed to salvage some data, but I can't salvage my Windows installation. Some file in the Windows directory somewhere is corrupt but scanning didn't show up any bad sectors so I have no further options.

Comment: Windows installation is the less relevant thing to worry about. If there is no actual sector damage, then you're in luck.

Comment: I re-installed Windows, which it warned incorrectly would wipe my data. It didn't wipe my data, it just backed up the old Windows directories. That worked. Now I'd like to resurrect my old Windows so I reinstated the old directories and am copying all the new DLLs from the good installation across. If this doesn't work, I'm going to chuck the machine out. Got a new one on its way.