# How can I read SMART data from my HDDs in Win7 recovery command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, smart

Win7 won't finish loading on my laptop, and I'm trying to find a way to get any tool, like `smartctl`, onto a USB stick so that I can check the hard drives.

I've used `wmic` which says the drives are OK, but I wanted to see if I could dig any deeper.

The problem with `smartctl` is that I can only download the Windows setup exe, which is no help since I've only got my laptop and a linux machine to work with. Obviously I should have installed `smartctl` before I had this issue :(

`hdtune` would have been good as well, but I can't run it from the command prompt, even if i could get it installed.

This question is a result of my earlier question [Intel RAID0 physical device error occurred(0), Win7 won't run but disks seem OK - is it salvageable?](https://superuser.com/questions/1128747/intel-raid0-physical-device-error-occurred0-win7-wont-run-but-disks-seem-ok)

I've seen this question below but can't use any of the solutions (except `wmci`)

[How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/29240/how-can-i-read-my-hard-drives-smart-status-in-windows-7)

Comment: Why not just boot to a Linux LiveUSB and [use a Linux SMART utility](http://superuser.com/questions/171195/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-hard-drive) to check the status?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/29240/173513). Corey's answer provides the information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use powershell, but it still doesn't give you much info:

Make sure your command prompt has elevated privileges (right click, run as admin) and type the following:

powershell "(Get-WmiObject -namespace root/wmi -class MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select PSComputerName, InstanceName, Active, PredictFailure, Reason | Format-Table -AutoSize)"

If PredictFailure is True, the drive has a problem.  The reason code could then be used to lookup the failure.  Each vendor uses their own set of reason codes.

Comment: Wouldn't this be the same info WMIC would provide?

Comment: Yes, you could use WMIC to get the same information.